# The Coordinator layout doesn't Scroll up for a specific position

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am facing this issue with coordinator layout about scrolling. For a specific position it wont scroll buy, After clicking on **Add new** button a list element gets added below. And if we scroll that item the coordinator layout behaves normally like expand and shrink. But when we try to scroll up by touching on the layout

**main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cord"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#4a90e2"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="#4a90e2"
        app:statusBarScrim="#4a90e2"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="120dp"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Suzuki Swift !"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="@font/latoregular"
                android:text="Some Text to enter about swift."/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/test_one"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/man"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/simple_view_behavior"
    app:behavior_dependsOn="@+id/app_bar"
    app:behavior_dependType="y"
    app:behavior_dependTarget="-176dp"
    app:behavior_targetX="16dp"
    app:behavior_targetY="8dp"
    app:behavior_targetWidth="40dp"
    app:behavior_targetHeight="40dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:text="Review For Swift"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:alpha="0"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/simple_view_behavior"
    app:behavior_dependsOn="@+id/app_bar"
    app:behavior_dependType="y"
    app:behavior_dependTarget="-206dp"
    app:behavior_targetY="0dp"
    app:behavior_targetAlpha="1"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Included Layout in main.xml i.e. test_one.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardOne"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLoutTwo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linearLoutOne"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">
            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/userName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/latoregular"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="Review For Swift add attributes below,"
                    android:textColor="@color/titleColor"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/white_border_round"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/latolight"
                    android:hint="Eg: Looks,Speed"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                    android:paddingStart="8dp"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/titleColor"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/add_row_button"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.096"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userName" />



                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/add_row_button"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="@color/titleColor"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/latobold"
                    android:onClick="addRow"
                    android:text="Add"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <com.example.android.uidesigns.XmlClasses.InsertionListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/cardOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_linear_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!--<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/image_view"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="80dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="80dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginStart="18dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginTop="8dp"-->
        <!--android:gravity="center_vertical"-->
        <!--android:src="@drawable/man"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />-->



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="#111"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have added a Gif to make my problem clear. Please take a look. 
----->[gif for understanding]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSGfX.gif

Comment: your coordinator layout is working accurately what do you expect exactly ?

Comment: @SantanuSur If you take a look at attached gif you'll get to know that am not able to scroll up by touching on a specific view. The view which has Add Button in it.

Comment: you mean the view with the add button cannot make it scroll up ryt ?

Comment: @SantanuSur Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

Rather than including the layout, I wrote it in the same file within NestedScrollView.

Somehow it worked. Thanks for the help.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```