# How to properly scroll nested-scrollview?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

How to properly scroll to a position in nestedscrollview which is inside a coordinate layout? When I use scrollTo(), it seems like the view inside AppBarLayout is loosing the ability to scroll down when I scroll to the end of NestedScrollView and coming back to top. What I need to know is how to programtically scroll to a position in nestedscrollview without causing problem with the normal behavior of collapsing layout.

Issue is similar to what is mentioned in this post:

[The Coordinator layout doesn't Scroll up for a specific position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169774/the-coordinator-layout-doesnt-scroll-up-for-a-specific-position)

There is a Gif attached along with the above question:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSGfX.gif

I have tried the solution in above link, but it is not working.

Comment: Please paste at least few lines of codes here...